# Error while printing sorted float array

Tags: c, sorting

> Write a program which should get 5 floating values from the user in an array using a function insert and then sort these values using a function sort after that print the sorted values on the screen using a function disp.

This is my code please tell me where i have done something wrong.It prints 0.000 after sorting.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void insert(float array[],int val);
void disp(float array[],int val);
void sort(float array[], int val);

void main ()
{
    float array[5],j;

    printf("Enter numbers: \n");
    insert(array,5);                 //array input function
    printf("Enter numbers are: \n");
    disp(array,5);                   //array output function
    sort(array,5);                   //array sort function
    printf("\nSorted Array is: \n");
    disp(array,5);                   //array output function
}

//array input function
void insert(float array[],int val)
{
    int k,i;
    for (k = 0;k<5;k++){
        scanf("%f",&array[k]);
    }
}

//array sort function
void sort(float array[], int val){
    int i,j;
    float hold;
    for(i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<6; j++)
        {
            if(array[j]>array[j+1])
            {
                hold=array[j];
                array[j]=array[j+1];
                array[j+1]=hold;
            }
        }
    }
}

//array display function
void disp(float array[],int val)
{
    int k;
    for (k = 0;k<5;k++){
        printf("%f\n",array[k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does sort loop between 0 and 5?

Comment: What's the use of val parameter in disp function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort function should look like this:

```
//array sort function
void sort(float array[], int val)
{
  int i,j;
  float hold;
  for(i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
    for(j=0; j<4; j++)
    {
      if(array[j]>array[j+1])
      {
        hold=array[j];
        array[j]=array[j+1];
        array[j+1]=hold;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the original code first loop executes two times too many.
Second loop causes reading beyond the array. Since you have 5 elements you need 4 comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you declared some variables that you didn't use, especially `int val` in your functions.
Secondly, you don't need to implement a function to insert values in an array, just loop it with a `scanf` directly.

Comment: Actually we are studying functions so our professor asked us to use separate function to get more used to functions.
int val is the length or array.